# Plotting Train/Val Accuracies on same graph when using queues

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

My input pipeline consists of a queue created using `tf.train.batch`. This forces me to make separate input queues for train and validation data. Hence for getting predictions, need to pass both the queues through the model (with `reuse=True` the second time).

Since now I have separate tensors for the train and validation prediction, I have to have separate `tf.summary.scalars` for them and they will come in separate graphs in tensorboard.

How can I make two different scalar summaries plotted in the same graph in 1.0?